# How to select background color of menu item

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a transparent menu in desktop but one of my menu items, `search adsler` has a  white background color. How can I select it to get rid of it? I also want to change the text colour to black from grey. Basically it should be like the other other menu items, `hover` and  `active` white, dormant =transparent.

Html:

```
<li id="menu-item-2952" class="fa fa-search menu-item 
menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu- 
item-2952"><a title="Search Adsler" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/">Search 
Adsler</a></li>
```

I tried:

```
a [href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/"] 
{background-color: transparent !important; color: black;}
```

Didn't work.

Page: https://adsler.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this code in your CSS file

```
 li#menu-item-2952 a {
        background-color: unset!important;
    }
    ul.dropdown-menu li a {
        color: black!important;
    }
li#menu-item-2952 a:hover {
   background-color: white!important;
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you'd know why, when I hover over the menu for a while, and then try to select an item, the menu disappears and I have to select the drop down again, going down again to the item I want to select?

Comment: That worked. Brilliant. Thanks dude. Just that it doesn't seem to be highlighting in white either in active or hover?

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing this in Css.

a [href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/"] 
{background-color: transparent !important; color: black;display:block;text-decoration: none;}

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between a and [, reason behind is that if there is a space between a selector it searches for a descendant of the previous element, in your case, a. So your selector would read as find me an element `[href...]` that is below an a-tag, so something like this: `<a> <[href=...]> </[href=...]> </a>`

Since you want to find an a with this attribute, you should omit the space:

```css
a[href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/"]  {color: green;}
```

```html
<ul>

<li id="menu-item-2952" class="fa fa-search menu-item  menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2952">
  <a title="Search Adsler" href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/">Search  Adsler</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline style declared.

```
a[href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/"] {

background-color: white;

}
```

Find this and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific class to it first, then modify the background on your .CSS :

Let's say `newClass` :

```
<li id="menu-item-2952" class="newClass fa fa-search menu-item 
menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu- 
item-2952"><a title="Search Adsler" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/">Search 
Adsler</a></li>
```

Then on CSS :

```
.newClass {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: grey;
}
```

Hope it helps, if you want to add another background color, just change the `background-color` element

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style in between a tag. Try this:

```
<li id="menu-item-2952" class="fa fa-search menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2952">
    <a title="Search Adsler" href="https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/" style="background:transparent;">
        Search Adsler
    </a>
</li>
```